# Selection a union of tables between a date range

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Im trying to select multiple tables where either the endDate or the startDate fall inot a range.

```
SELECT *
FROM excel.construction
GROUP BY startDate,
         endDate
UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM excel.misc
GROUP BY startDate,
         endDate
UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM excel.spawar
GROUP BY startDate,
         endDate
WHERE construction.startDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-10'
  OR construction.endDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-10'
  OR misc.startDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-10'
  OR misc.endDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-10';
```

Why wouldn't this work/is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You need to give us some background on the structure of your database in order for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

A few things

This 3 select must have the same number and type of column

```
SELECT * FROM excel.construction  
SELECT * FROM excel.misc 
SELECT * FROM excel.spawar
```

the where condition must be related to the proper query

```
SELECT * 
    FROM excel.construction 
    where construction.startDate  BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-10' 
    OR construction.endDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-10'
    group by startDate,endDate
UNION ALL 
select * 
    FROM excel.misc 
    where misc.startDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-10' OR 
         misc.endDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-10';m       
    group by  startDate, endDate 
UNION ALL 
select * 
    from excel.spawar 
group by startDate, endDate
```